# Incompatible types. Required: GoogleApiClient Found: GoogleApiClient.Builder

Tags: google-api-client

I am trying to get the last known location using Google API client, but I have an issue with it being incompatible. Can anyone point out what did I miss?

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, OnConnectionFailedListener,
        ConnectionCallbacks{

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        // getting incompatible issue in below line
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this);

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready           to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).build();
```